# difference between assigning S4 to a list with "[" vs. "[["

Tags: r, operators, r-s4

I'm missing something in how the **[<-** and the **[[<-**  operators work with S4 objects. Here's a quick sample.  Looks like the **[<-** operator is somehow diving one slot-level down in the assignment (apologies for the clumsy lingo).    What is actually going on ?

```
> blist <- list()
> blist[[1]] <- mpfr(5,10)
> blist[2] <- mpfr(7,10)
> blist
[[1]]
1 'mpfr' number of precision  10   bits 
[1] 5

[[2]]
'mpfr1' 7

> slotNames(blist[[2]])
[1] "prec" "exp"  "sign" "d"   
> slotNames(blist[[1]])
[1] ".Data"

> mp1d <- blist[[1]]@.Data
> mp1d
[[1]]
'mpfr1' 5

> slotNames(mp1d[[1]])
[1] "prec" "exp"  "sign" "d"
```

Comment: What version of R? I get different results plus a warning about implicit list embedding of S4 objects?

Comment: @SmokeyShakers  R 4.05 on windows 10,  and  R 4.1.2 on MacOS Big Sur

Comment: Thank you. I see it now. I was recreating with a simpler S4 object (one level of slots), not the `mpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blist` is a list.  Assigning to `blist[[1]]` should always assign the object into that location.  Assigning to `blist[1]` needs to convert the RHS into a length 1 list, then puts its entry into that position.

But the way `Rmpfr::mpfr` objects are created is as list objects with a formal class.  So the conversion to list just drops the formal class.  Here are the first two lines of the `mpfr` class definition:

```
setClass("mpfr", ## a *vector* of "mpfr1", i.e., multi-precision float numbers
         contains = "list", ## of "mpfr1" entries:
```

The `contains = "list"` part says that `mpfr` is derived from `list`.